# Insert every other object from one NSMutableArray into another NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I'm trying to add every other object from one NSMutableArray to another.
Here is my code so far.

```
for (int i = 0; i < all.count; i ++) {
    [cat insertObject:all atIndex:0];
    [all removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

It did not add anything from the mutableArray called all, to the mutableArray called cat.
I would like to remove all even objects from one array and put it to the next to the next.

Comment: You see that `i` thingie?  You probably need to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting the array `all` into `cat`. You should be taking `all`'s element instead, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < all.count; i += 2) {
    [cat addObject:[all objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

or use the square bracket syntax for accessing array elements of `all`, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < all.count; i += 2) {
    [cat addObject:all[i]];
}
```

Comment: Even more concise, modern notation: `[cat addObject:all[i]]`

Comment: @Mike You didn't forget to replace your `>` with `<` the way it's shown in the answer, did you?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just changed it and it worked!! Now how do I remove the object from all. Note: it's a NSArray.

Comment: @Mike Since `NSArray` is immutable, you cannot remove objects from it. You can create a temporary mutable array with the objects that you want to keep, and assign it back to `all` when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to be sure that your cat object has been previously initialized with an empty `NSMutableArray`.

Then the code for passing every other object from one to another could look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [all count]; i++) {
    id item = [all objectAtIndex:i];
    [cat addObject:item];
    [all removeObject:item];
}
```

This would iterate from 0 to all.count, add the object at an index to the `cat` array and delete it from the `all` array. You don't need to iterate with `i += 2` because the way the removeObject works, it shifts the indexes of the remaining objects to fill the space of the object removed.

Let's say you removed the index 0, then the index 1 will be the new index 0, so for you to go to your original index 2 you will only need to go to your new index 1.

Comment: I updated my Question. Also, removeObjectAtIndext I don't think it works with NSMutableArray, because it gave me an error.

Comment: By me, it works perfectly without the '/ 2', but thanks for pointing out the i++, that was a real life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the cat array in one shot like this 
NSArray* cat =[NSArray arrayWithArray:all];